# How to pass java uuid as message property in mule

Tags: jms, mule, correlation

I have a message which involves multiple jms queue interaction. In order co related all the logs, I want to set java uuid/message.id as log prefix. So I am setting this as a outbound property.

But after the second queue receiver and when I want print this property, its giving null. If I put any string its working but when I put uuid, Its giving null value.

Can you please provide any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outbound properties are automatically turned into inbound properties and are lost when crossing a transport barrier. If you want to use outbound properties make sure to set the property again after each queue, or you can just use a session property since these variables are not lost when crossing a transport barrier.

For more information regarding property scopes, you can check this [blogpost](http://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/anypoint-platform-dev/mule-school-the-mulemessage-property-scopes-and-variables/).

Comment: I know the property scopes. SO outbound property become inbound after crossing a transport. My concern is when I put uuid as a property its not passing but random string is passing. SO is there any restriction with respec to length